# Submit in jquery with data-attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I had a cshtml file like this.. I had so many elements I excluded that.. as my problem was with this button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFutureClaim", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<div class=".divclassname">
   <input type="button" name="buttonftcl" value="Create" data-slmgui-name="Claimsub"/>
</div>
}
```

Now by using data attribute of the button I want to submit the form by using `.submit()`.

here the divElement is $(".divclassname").

```
var submitbuttonele = $(divElement).find("[data-slmgui-name= Claimsub]");

$(submitbuttonele).click(function () {

    alert("calling submit");

   var formdata =  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();

   alert(formdata);
 });
 }
```

when i click the button the alert is calling fine i.e for fromdata it returns `alert [object][Object]`. But the form is not submitting that is I cannot able to get the call for the Action in the controller.

I had checked view source it was like..

```
<form action="/Home/CreateFutureClaim" id="futureclaimform" method="post">
```

Contoller action:

```
[HttpPost] 
public void CreateFutureClaim(ClaimModel claim) 
{ 
}
```

But I cannot able to get the call for the action in the home controller. Can any one please help me to find the solution?

Comment: Post routing setup and the contoller

Comment: this is the api in the home controller..  [HttpPost]
        public void CreateFutureClaim(ClaimModel claim)
        {
        }

Comment: Try You gets breakpoint at public void CreateFutureClaim ? Do You get there ?

Comment: no i had placed break point. But i could get.

Answer (score 0):

Try some [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx), there can be problem with routing, You can just don't get right route.